# AWS SageMaker studio CreateDomain Access error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to setup sagemaker studio using quickstart method. I have IAM role with the `AmazonSageMakerFullAccess` added to it. After selecting the VPC/subnet, I'm getting the below error,

```
AccessDeniedException
User: arn:aws:iam::1234567:user/blahblah is not authorized to perform: 
      sagemaker:CreateDomain 
      on resource: arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-1:2345678:domain/d-hj4oh0jk7g6v
```

How do I fix this access issue?

Comment: Hi, I am encountering the same issue, do you remember how you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

attach these policies to role

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:CreateGrant",
                "kms:DescribeKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:region:account-id:key/kms-key-id"
        },
    ]
```

try this link
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sagemaker-roles.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sagemaker-roles.html#sagemaker-roles-createdomain-perms,

CreateNotebookInstance API: Execution Role Permissions

this will help you ...

Answer (score 0):

It is cumbersome indeed. Assuming that your user has access to IAM, go there, create a new policy and attach the following permissions:

```
1. Service: IAM. Action: CreateServiceLinkedRole
2. Service: IAM. Action: PassRole
3. Service: SageMaker. Action: CreateDomain
4. Service: SageMaker. Action: AddTags
5. Service: SageMaker. Action: CreateUserProfile
6. Service: Service Catalog. Action: ListAcceptedPortfolioShares
```

Then attach this new policy to your user. They should be able to create the domain on SageMaker.